# Swift: Referencing variable from class array into string for UITableView

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create my first app (yay!) and need some help.
I'm trying to make a custom class called Medication, where I can store information about a certain medication and present a list of Medications for a person to choose from (in a table view).
I created my new class Medication as such:

```
class Medication: NSObject {
var name: String
var bottleColor: UIColor
var usage: String
var patientMed: Bool = false
var eye: String

init(name: String, bottleColor:UIColor, usage:String, eye: String, patientMed:Bool) {
self.name = name
self.bottleColor = bottleColor
self.usage = usage
self.patientMed = patientMed
self.eye = eye 
}
}
```

I created a variable to store an array of Medication:

```
var fullMedsList = [Medication]()
```

I created a function to append data into the array, but then when I try to reference this into a table view, I can't figure out how to pull out the appropriate data.
Here is my code and the area I can't figure out:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.myMedsList.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{

let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
cell.textLabel!.text = myMedsList.name[indexPath.row]

return cell
}
```

I get an error saying ((Medication)) does not have a member named 'name' on this line:
    cell.textLabel!.text = myMedsList.name[indexPath.row]
The question is, how do I reference out the name data from my Medication class into a tableview? Ideally, I want to reference the Medication.name and have a subtitle of Medication.usage but I am just trying to get the basics down first!
I appreciate your help r/swift!

Comment: what about `cell.textLabel!.text = myMedsList[indexPath.row].name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in
    `myMedsList.name[indexPath.row]`, you are trying to get the `indexPath.row`th element in an array named name.
But this is not what you wanted : get the name of the `indexPath.row`th index of the `myMedList`that  way :

```
cell.textLabel!.text = myMedsList[indexPath.row].name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your name is not an array. Its a string. Do like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{

let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
let med = myMedsList[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel!.text = med.name
cell.detailLabel.text = med.usage

return cell
}
```

Comment: Was it helpful to you?